# .indexOf "-1" is being skipped by my if statement

Tags: java, indexof

Here I separate a string into separate words and then add `"ay"` to the end of each word if it contains a vowel, however the problem is when I reach the last word `indexOf` is `-1`so it is automaticly skipped by my if statement. To fix this I tried adding an `if (i ==-1)` however when I stepped through it with the debugger it automatically skips this if statement! Does anybody know why? And how can work around this issue and add `"ay"` to the last word even if `.indexOf is -1`

Method:

```
    public static void pigLatin(String sentence){
    sentence = sentence.trim();

    if(sentence.length()> 0){
        int i = sentence.indexOf(" ");
        String word = sentence.substring(0, i);
        if(i == -1){ //this  if statement is ignored
            if (word.contains("a") || word.contains("i") || word.contains("o") || word.contains("e") || word.contains("u")){
                System.out.println(word + "ay");
            } else{
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
        if(i != -1){
            if(word.contains("a") || word.contains("i") || word.contains("o") || word.contains("e") || word.contains("u")){
                System.out.println(word + "ay");
                pigLatin(sentence.substring(i));
            } else if(!word.contains("a") || !word.contains("i") || !word.contains("o") || !word.contains("e") || !word.contains("u")){
                System.out.println(word);
                pigLatin(sentence.substring(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = in.nextLine();
    Functions.pigLatin(word);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us example input that shows your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems.

- The two lines that say `pigLatin(sentence.substring(i))` should say `pigLatin(sentence.substring(i+1))` - otherwise you just see the same space over and over.
- the line that says `else if(!word.contains("a") ||  ...` COULD just say `else`, but if you insist on writing it in full, you must use `&&` where you have `||`.

Comment: Yes it does.  If you keep saying the same space over and over (as per my first bullet point), you'll never get to `i==-1`.